# ISBN check digit calculation problems

Tags: python, digit, isbn

can any one offer any assistance, as to why the following code always returns the same check digit number?

```
    def ISBN():
        numlist = []
        request = raw_input("Please enter the 10 digit number:  ")
        if len(request) == 10:
            listofnums = [int(digit) for digit in '1234567890']
            multipliers = reversed(range(2,12))
            multipliednums = [a*b for a,b in zip(listofnums, multipliers)]
            print multipliednums
            added_result = sum(multipliednums)
            print added_result
            remainder = added_result % 11
            print remainder
            check_digit = 11 - remainder
            print check_digit
            ISBN()
        if len(request) != 10:
            print "Invalid Input"
            ISBN()

    ISBN()
```

any information or tips on how i could imptove the code, or just why it constantly eturns the same digit(9) no matter what the input.
Thank you

Comment: One tip: don't recursively call ISBN.  Use a `while True:` block if you want to do something forever: as it stands, if I enter enough ISBN numbers I can crash the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

I think `for digit in '1234567890'` should be `for digit in request`.

Comment: This.  Also, pretty sure you posted a question about this before... in any case, yeah, be careful of copy pasting code.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you can see that you accept the value of `request` from the user, but after checking its length, you don't do anything else with it again. There's no way the output of this program could change.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be calculating anything on the variable that you ask from the user.
Variable request is not used in the subsequent code...